# Access Lead conversion field mappings from Apex?

Tags: lead-conversion

I've written some Apex code to override the lead conversion process.  if the contact exists, the client wants to update all the contact fields with the lead field data when the lead field is not null.

There are over 40 field mappings.  Is there a way to access the field mappings table so I don't have to hardcode the field names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is possible to retrieve Lead Conversion fields through Apex with help of Metadata API. To use this code you need to have MetadataService class from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

List<MetadataService.LeadConvertSettings> leadConvertSettings = (List<MetadataService.LeadConvertSettings>) service.readMetadata('LeadConvertSettings', new List<String>{'LeadConvertSettings'}).getRecords();

for (MetadataService.LeadConvertSettings leadConvertSetting : leadConvertSettings) {
    for (MetadataService.ObjectMapping objectMapping : leadConvertSetting.objectMapping) {
        System.debug(objectMapping.inputObject + ' -> ' + objectMapping.outputObject);
        for (MetadataService.ObjectMappingField fieldMapping : objectMapping.mappingFields) {
            System.debug('\t' + fieldMapping.inputField + ' -> ' + fieldMapping.outputField);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately the Lead Conversion field mappings aren't available in APEX or the Metadata API

Comment: I suspected this myself, but I couldn't find the documentation that proves it. Do you have a link?

Comment: Any time-saving solution or answer?

Comment: @SFDC_peter sorry, no

Comment: It is as for Winter '22 is available in [metadata api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177170/how-to-retrieve-leadconvertsettings-with-force-com-migration-toolkit)