# How To Retrieve LeadConvertSettings with Force.com Migration Toolkit

Tags: metadata, lead-conversion, ant, migration-tool

I've been trying to retrieve Lead Conversion field mappings in order to add them to Metadata for deployment. I noted in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_leadconvertsettings.htm that Lead conversion settings should be available since API version 39.0.  I've tried

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```

and this returns all settings except Lead settings. 
I've even tried

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LeadConversionSettings</name>
</types>
```

Even though I'd guessed this would not work.

I have the Version 39 ant-salesforce.jar file and have specified     39.0 in my package.xml file but no dice so far.

Does anyone know hot to retrieve the LeadConversion Mappings to allow them to be deployed via metadata instead of requiring a manual post deployment step.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 7):

In package.xml file with 39 version of API. It works

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LeadConvertSettings</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Hi, Should field mappings come over? I've used     <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadConvertSettings</name>
    </types>   and no metadata has been retrieved.       Thanks.

Comment: @FRed can you please double-check API version of your package.xml file

Comment: Hi Alexander, The following is my full Package.xml file.   
 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadConvertSettings</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: what command are you using for ant? Can you copy body of it?

Comment: Hi. Just "ant retrieveCode".     Thanks.

Comment: The build.xml definition being     <target name="retrieveCode">
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="MainBuild" unpackaged="MainBuild/package.xml"/>
    </target>

Answer (score 0):

I logged a ticket with Salesforce Support and they had to enable it on their end by instance (Sandboxes and Production).

Comment: Hi SHeila, Did "ant retrieve' work after this was enabled? I don't need it anymore but I'm curious to know. I never got it to work when I required it.